# Which jars am I missing out, which jar needs to be added here?

Tags: spring-mvc, exception, jar, frameworks, spring-framework-beans

"{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"underwriting.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"underwriting.war\"
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.underwriting.war\" from Service Module Loader
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/ExpressionParser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser from [Module \"deployment.underwriting.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}"

I have added spring-expression-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar still getting this issue. Even tried adding manually in the classpath file. Still getting this error